# C# init é igual private set?

Tags: c#

Estava lendo sobre as novas implementações no `C# 9` e me deparei com o `init`, [init-only-setters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#init-only-setters):

> Starting with C# 9.0, you can create init accessors instead of set
> accessors for properties and indexers.

Em tradução livre:

> A partir do C# 9.0, você pode criar "assessores" `init` em vez de
> definir assessores `set` para propriedades e indexadores.

Vendo o exemplo de código abaixo:

```
public class Pessoa
{ 
  public string Nome { get; init; } 
  public string Idade { get; set; } 
}
```

Pode-se instanciar a classe assim, "no construtor":

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa
{
    Nome = "Fulano",
    Idade = 20
};
```

A propriedade `Idade` pode ser mudada depois da instância, mas o mesmo não acontece com a propriedade `Nome`:

```
pessoa.Nome = "Outro";  // isso dá erro
```

Isso não é o mesmo que declarar a propriedade `Nome` deste jeito?

```
public string Nome { get; private set; }
```

Se sim, existe alguma vantagem em usar o `init` no lugar do `private set`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Os comportamentos dos dois modificadores de acesso são bem diferentes. O fato de não ser possível alterar o valor da propriedade fora da classe é a única semelhança mesmo.

Na verdade, as propriedades *init-only* têm mais semelhança com propriedades *getter-only*. Neste caso a diferença é que as propriedades *init-only* podem ser inicializadas na construção de um objeto ([usando a sintaxe de inicialização de objetos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers)) e as propriedades *getter-only* só podem ser inicializadas em um construtor propriamente dito.

Voltando pras diferenças entre *init-only* e *setter* privado. Vamos usar como base a classe abaixo.

```cs
public class Pessoa
{    
    public string Nome { get; init; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; private set; }
}
```

A propriedade com o modificador *init* não podem ter seu valor alterado mesmo dentro de classe `Pessoa`. Neste caso o compilador emite o [erro CS0272](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0272).

```cs
public class Pessoa
{ 
    // ...
     
    void AlterarNome(string novoNome, string novoSobrenome) 
    {
        // Isso é inválido! 
        Nome = novoNome;
    
        // Isso é válido!
        Sobrenome = novoSobrenome;    
    }
}
```

Além disso, como dito anteriormente, a propriedade *init-only* pode ser inicializada durante a criação de um objeto. Já a propriedade com *setter* privado não pode ter seu valor definido assim, se tentar fazer isso o compilador vai emitir o erro CS8852 (não consegui encontrar o link pra este erro na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/)).

```
var objeto = new Pessoa
{
    Nome = "Matheus",   // Isso é válido
    Sobrenome = "Silva" // Isso não é válido
};
```

Comment: É bom notar que nesta resposta falo sobre as diferenças entre a **utilização** dos modificadores. Se formos falar do IL gerado o _init_ é muito mais parecido com o _set_ (ele é de fato um método _setter_ - inclusive me parece que ele é um _setter_ **público** que tem o acesso controlado apenas a nível de compilação mesmo).

Comment: boa resposta, então o `private set` é algo que só pode ser modificado no escopo privado da classe, seja na contrução ou não, e o `init` só ao instanciar o objeto é isso?

Comment: É isso aí mesmo.